# SQL Server - inner join when updating

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have the below query which does not work. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

```
UPDATE ProductReviews AS R 
   INNER JOIN products AS P 
       ON R.pid = P.id 
SET R.status = '0' 
WHERE R.id = '17190' 
  AND P.shopkeeper = '89137'
```

Comment: UPDATE dbo.ProductReviews AS R
SET R.status = '0' 
INNER JOIN dbo.products AS P 
       ON R.pid = P.id 
WHERE R.id = '17190' 
  AND P.shopkeeper = '89137';

Comment: This is not a duplicate because he is not trying to update one table FROM another.  He is only joining to enforce the where clause.

Answer (score 924, accepted):

```
UPDATE R 
SET R.status = '0' 
FROM dbo.ProductReviews AS R
INNER JOIN dbo.products AS P 
       ON R.pid = P.id 
WHERE R.id = '17190' 
  AND P.shopkeeper = '89137';
```

Comment: can you please explain why syntax alike UPDATE JOIN SET WHERE is incorrect, but it works with UDPATE SET FROM JOIN WHERE? Does it depend on the version of mysql?

Comment: @Farside this syntax is for SQL Server. Someone else will have to help you with MySQL syntax, sorry.

Answer (score 75):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE ProductReviews
SET    ProductReviews.status = '0'
FROM   ProductReviews
       INNER JOIN products
         ON ProductReviews.pid = products.id
WHERE  ProductReviews.id = '17190'
       AND products.shopkeeper = '89137'
```

Comment: this gives me `ERROR: table name "ProductReviews" specified more than once` in postgresql

Comment: fixed it by doing `FROM ProductReviews AS pr` also `SET status = '0'` instead of `ProductReviews.status = '0'`

Comment: @JohhanSantana This question was tagged SQL server - no guarantee it'll work on other DBMS systems.