# How to update a query

Tags: sql

How can I update some fields of a select? (something like the following)

```
update (select *
        from Students s
        join Father f on s.fId=f.Id
        where s.Id=12)
set f.FirstName='John'
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Update Students
set FirstName='John'
where Id=12
```

No need of a select in this case. Check the link [SQL UPDATE Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) for more details.

In your case you can use [SQL Server - inner join when updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588423/sql-server-inner-join-when-updating)

```
UPDATE f
SET FirstName='John'
FROM Students s JOIN Father f 
    ON s.fId=f.Id 
WHERE s.Id=12
```

Comment: `FirstName` belongs to which table?

Comment: It belongs to table Father.

Comment: Note that the update-with-join syntax is different for different DBMSes. I see nothing indicating that MS SQL Server is the right technology in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Students
SET FirstName='John'
WHERE ID = 12
```

That should work for you  :)

Answer (score 0):

To update `FirstName` of a `Student` with a specific `Id` do the following:

```
update Students 
set FirstName='John'
where Id=12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Join update for this kind of situation. for a example if you need to set the fathers surname for his son, You can use a query like this.

```
UPDATE SonsDetails SET Surname = Father.Surname
FROM [dbo].[SonDetails] AS SonsDetails INNER JOIN [dbo].[FatherDetails] Father 
ON [SonsDetails].[FatherId] = Father.Id
```

Comment: Note that this syntax will be different for different DBMSes, because it is not in the SQL standard. The example you gives looks like MS SQL Server to me, but there's no clue in the question that this is the system the questioner is using.