# Difficulty querying two tables in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database in MYSQL and it contains 2 tables:

```
Table: political_party
+----------+--------------------+-------+
| party_id | party_abbreviation | party |
+----------+--------------------+-------+

Table: polling_party_result
+----+------+-----------------+
| id | p_id | number_of_votes |
+----+------+-----------------+
```

I am writing a PHP program that outputs a form, which UPDATES the political_party_result table WHERE the id runs from 1 to X.. The problem I'm facing is that **on** the form, the id relates to the party_abbreviation column in the above political_party table.

That is 1(in the political_party_result table) should bring out AP(from the political_party table) 
2 = ADC
3 = PDP
etc..

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HTML INEC</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="inechp.php" method="post" name="form1">
ID: <input name="id" type="text" /> <br /> <br />
Polling Unit: <input name="pid" type="text" /> <br /> <br />
Number of Votes: <input name="votes" type="text" /> <br /> <br />
<input type="submit" /> <br />
</form>

<form action="inechp.php" method="post" name="form2">
Polling Unit: <input name="unit" type="text" /> <br />
Number of Votes: <input name="nov" type="text" /> <br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "inec_results");

mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE inec_results.polling_party_result SET p_id ='$_POST[pid]' , number_of_votes = '$_POST[votes]' WHERE id = '$_POST[id]'");
?>
```

Forgive me if my explanations weren't satisfactory as I'm bit new to PHP.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you're using mysqli and concatenating $_POST variables directly into the SQL string - that's insecure. You should look at using a prepared statement and bound variables instead.

Comment: `polling_party_result` or `political_party_result` ?

Comment: Sorry, *polling_party_result.

Comment: You have to do an `inner join`.

Comment: Could you please help me out with that

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588423/sql-server-inner-join-when-updating helps...

Comment: It's easier to use OO mysqli imho. $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }
            $admin = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname =\"". $_POST["username"] ."\" AND pwd = \"".$_POST["password"]."\" AND `admin`=1";
            $isadmin = $mysqli->query($admin) or die($mysqli->error);

Comment: o0rebelious0o your answer is showing a bad way to code. Your introducing a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You probably want to make a pull down menu in your form to let people `select` one of the available parties. In the processing script, you might want to _check_ that the returned value is valid (ie. an _integer_ between `1` and `X`), and then use a properly parameterized query. Please look up both concepts, try implementing them, and come back with a more specific question if you get stuck later on.

Comment: You're welcome. There are a lot of questions and answers here you could draw some inspiration from. Please look on the right side of the page for questions dealing with similar topics.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE inec_results.polling_party_result SET p_id ='$_POST[pid]' , number_of_votes = '$_POST[votes]' WHERE id = '$_POST[id]'");
```

This is bad for a number of reasons.

Firstly your not validating that the form data you have received is valid. E.g I enter an email address for your ID field and you just pass that directly to your database. This  also leads onto the second big issue.

You should never place post data directly into SQL, as andrew mentions this is very insecure and a malicious user could quite easily drop  your entire database by SQL injection.

Having said that I am not sure you are actually passing your post variables (its been a little while since I touched PHP) because the entire statement is in double quotes. This means those '$_POST[var]' parts are actually just being read in as part of the string literal. (Meaning your always passing the value $_POST[var] instead of the value from your form. You would need to brace or fullstop the vars '{$_POST[var]}' or '.$_POST[var].'(BUT AGAIN THIS IS BAD!).

What you should do is as mentioned used a prepared statement after you have validated your data. You can see a good example here [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)