# mysql update column inner join another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a field based on a field of another table. Here is the code:

```
UPDATE h 
SET h.strength = c.strength 
FROM hesters AS h 
INNER JOIN campers AS c 
ON h.camper_id = c.id
```

Getting "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

I'm basing my code off this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588423/sql-server-inner-join-when-updating).

Anyone spot the syntax error?

Comment: You might want to do a select instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the code from the previous linked answer didn't work, but here is what I ended up going with, from the mysql documentation on [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) (search for "join").

```
UPDATE hesters AS h,campers AS c 
SET h.strength = c.strength 
WHERE h.camper_id = c.id
```

Comment: That's because the linked answer belongs to SQL Server, **not** MySQL (which is what you're using).  No two RDBMS vendor implements features in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like:

```
UPDATE hesters AS h 
INNER JOIN campers AS c 
ON h.camper_id = c.id
SET h.strength = c.strength
```

---

***update***

This works on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff5ed3/1).

Comment: syntax error. Also using an alias for a table name shouldn't effect this.

Comment: @themerlinproject it works on sql fiddle though. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your `JOIN` clause before your `SET` clause, and your `h` alias needs to be set at the beginning:

```
UPDATE hesters AS h 
INNER JOIN campers AS c 
ON h.camper_id = c.id
SET h.strength = c.strength
```

Comment: This gives the same error. I found the correct syntax in the mysql documentation.