# UPDATE on inner join with another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update users.banned values only where the age is 21, and the users_auth.email matches the ban_users.email.  (ban_users is a separate table)

```
UPDATE users_auth
SET users_auth.banned = '1'
WHERE age='21'
INNER JOIN ban_users
ON users_auth.email = ban_users.email
```

I have found these two posts but both dont seem to help.

[SQL Server - inner join when updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588423/sql-server-inner-join-when-updating)

[How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is not correct it should be as below.

```
UPDATE users_auth
INNER JOIN ban_users
ON users_auth.email = ban_users.email
SET users_auth.banned = '1'
WHERE age='21'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE ua
SET banned = '1'
FROM users_auth ua
INNER JOIN ban_users
ON ua.email = ban_users.email
WHERE age='21'
```