# SQL Update Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 40,000 rows in my database that I need to update. However my select query that I have used is across two tables.

Example of my select query below:

```
select t1.*, t2.data, t2.more_data, t2.more_data2 
from table1 as t1, table2 as t2
where 
DATE(t1.date) >= '2014-10-23'
and
t1.direction = 10
and
t1.date_read is NULL
and
t1.fk_client is NULL
and
t1.id=t2.id
and
t2.data = 'this is dummy text';
```

I've been looking through other peoples requests on this, but I just cannot seem to get my head round it.

EDIT:

What I am wanting to do is to update `t1.date_read` with `2015-03-17 09:00:00` where `t2.data` is equal to `'this is dummy test'`

Comment: Which columns you want to update and with what values?

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: there  is no `t3` table declared in query for your `t3.more_data2`

Comment: I can see multiple problems with your query... Missing `.` in the `SELECT`, missing closing quotes on both your date and data fields, missing table references (t3), an unusual `DATE` cast of a column named date, use of a `JOIN` syntax that has been deprecated for over 20 years...  But what exactly is your question here?

Comment: String start with single quote but ending quote not present

Comment: Sorry missed out the . and t3 was wrongly put in, should have been t2. What I am wanting to do is to update t1.date_read with 2015-03-17 09:00:00 where t2.data = 'this is dummy test'

Comment: @Bromers Please update your question to reflect that.

Comment: seem that what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588423/sql-server-inner-join-when-updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am wanting to do is to update `t1.date_read` with `2015-03-17 09:00:00` where `t2.data` is equal to `'this is dummy test'`

Just stick a reference to the other table in the `WHERE` clause of your update like so:

```
UPDATE table1
SET date_read = '2015-03-17 09:00:00'
where table1.id IN (SELECT id from table1 as t1
                    INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
                    WHERE t2.data = 'this is dummy test')
```

If you want to include the other parameters you typed out in your question, just add them at the end...

```
--[code from above]
AND
DATE(table1.date) >= '2014-10-23'
AND
table1.direction = 10
AND
table1.date_read is NULL
AND
table1.fk_client is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have some errors in your query

1. `t1*` missing dot -> `t1.*`
2. `t3.more_data2` - t3 is not decared in query
3. `t2.data = 'this is dummy text;` missed close quote
4. unclear join tables key

So try this corrected query and try to explain your goals:

```
SELECT
   t1.*,
   t2.data, 
   t2.more_data
FROM
   table1 as t1, 
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT *
    FROM   table2 
    WHERE
      data = 'this is dummy text'
   ) as t2
ON 
   t1.id=t2.id
WHERE 
   DATE(t1.date) >= '2014-10-23
   AND
   t1.direction = 10
   AND
   t1.date_read is NULL
   AND
   t1.fk_client is NULL
```