# Update MySQL column from another table column only if the autoincrement data is equal

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 2 tables. In table1 there are two column:

columnA (autoincrement) and columnB (text)

And in table2:
columnC (autoincrement) and columnD (text)

I want to replace (copy) data in columnB with data from columnD only if the autoincrement columns are equals.

I tried with this, but its not correct:

```
UPDATE table1 
   SET columnB = (
      SELECT columnD 
      FROM table2 WHERE (
         SELECT columnA FROM table1 = SELECT columnC FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update it by an UPDATE with an INNER JOIN:

```
UPDATE `table1` as a
INNER join table2 b on a.columnA = b.columnC
SET a.`columnB` = b.`columnD`
-- WHERE clause if needed ...
```

> See:
>   [SQL Server - inner join when updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588423/sql-server-inner-join-when-updating)

Comment: I have updated the code for MySQL. Can you try it again?

Comment: I missed the alias `a` and `b`. Here's an update: http://pastie.org/10709664. Are those tables and columns above do exists in your database?

Answer (score -1):

You can use left join:
`UPDATE table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.columnA=t2.columnC set t1.columnB=t2.columnD where t2.columnc is not null`

Comment: This is a long winded way of writing an inner join

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to update columnB with one query, which means regardless of whether columnA and columnC are equal. I'd suggest creating a procedure, implementing the if statement there and then simply calling the procedure.