# Insert values from another table based on select with parameters (unique keys)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, updates, insert-update

I have added to my existing table1 new column (col7). Structure is as below on picture. Here is the SQL statement which produces the table:

```
select year, month, quater, col4, col5, col6, col7 from table1
```

[image]

Based on table2, I want to update values into col7 in table1 (insert all values from table2 to table1).

**My unique key is**: year-month-quater-col4-col5-col6

Here is structure of table2:
[image]

I didn't do before this update. Can you kindly please help how to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query

```
UPDATE T1 
SET T1.Col7 = T2.Col7
FROM table1 T1 
inner join table2 T2 on T1.Year = T2.Year AND T1.month = T2.month AND T1.quarter = T2.quarter AND T1.col4 = T2.col4 AND T1.col5= T2.col5 AND T1.col6 = T2.col6
```

Refer below link
[SQL Server - inner join when updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588423/sql-server-inner-join-when-updating)

Comment: if you want to insert all the records from Table2 to Table1 you can use insert select statement.

Comment: I want update values and also, if record is in table2 but missing in table1, should be also insert

Answer (score 1):

If you have record in table2 but missing in table1 then you can insert into table1 by following code, Apart for the update code which is provided by @arpan desai, you need to use the below code for inserting your missing record

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT  T2.year,T2.month,T2.quarter,T2.COL4,T2.COL5,T2.COL6,T2.COL7 FROM TABLE2 T2
EXCEPT
SELECT  T1.year,T1.month,T1.quarter,T1.COL4,T1.COL5,T1.COL6,T1.COL7 FROM TABLE1 T1) M
```

Comment: thanks! so I will update all records and then run your code