# sql update with inner join and where

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, syntax-error

```
UPDATE newsreactions
SET newsreactions.enabled = '0'
FROM newsreactions
INNER JOIN users ON newsreactions.memberId = users.id
WHERE users.active =  '0' AND users.comment LIKE  '%spam%'
```

For some reason I'm getting a syntax error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM newsreactions INNER JOIN users ON newsreactions.memberId = users.id WHERE u' at line 3

Can't figure it out though.
If I replace the `update` and `set` by a `select` it works fine.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Syntax for MySQL multi table UPDATE statement is available here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error 1064 is a MySQL syntax error.  The correct MySQL syntax is:

```
UPDATE newsreactions nr INNER JOIN
       users u
       ON nr.memberId = u.id
    SET nr.enabled = 0
WHERE u.active =  0 AND u.comment LIKE '%spam%';
```

Notes:

- The `JOIN` goes in the `UPDATE` clause.
- Table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.
- I am guessing that `enabled` and `active` are really numeric values.  If so, do not use single quotes.

Comment: Thx! I used the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588423/sql-server-inner-join-when-updating
How is my question different from it?

Comment: @PascalClaes: That other question concerns Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL. Those are different DBMS, and there are some significant differences in SQL syntax. The multi-table UPDATE syntax is an example of one of those differences. That's a big reason it's important to identify which database you are using (asking about).

Answer (score 2):

The `join` clause should come before the `set` clause, and there should be no `from` clause in MySQL:

```
UPDATE newsreactions 
JOIN   users ON newsreactions.memberId = users.id
SET    newsreactions.enabled = '0'
WHERE  users.active =  '0' AND users.comment LIKE  '%spam%'
```