# Update Table Based on Existing ID with Inner Join & Update

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to pull data from an existing table (wp_postmeta) and insert the meta_value into the new table (cigar_flavor_scoring). The data should be based on the post_id and I only want to pull in data from the wp_postmeta table with a meta_key of 'caramel'. I want to then take that value and insert it into the cigar_flavor_scoring table, column caramel.

I feel like I'm very close.

```
 SELECT meta_value
    FROM wp_postmeta
    UPDATE cigar_flavor_scoring
    INNER JOIN cigar_flavor_scoring ON (wp_postmeta.post_id = cigar_flavor_scoring.post_id)
    WHERE meta_key = "caramel"
    SET cigar_flavor_scoring.caramel = wp_postmeta.meta_value
```

Comment: Are you trying to _insert_ new data into `cigar_flavor_scoring` or are you trying to _update_ already existing records in this table?

Comment: I'm not feeling it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well the rows are already there with the post_id number column, not the rest of the columns are blank. So I'm assuming I am updating vs inserting.

Comment: Well I figured this it out and it worked:

`UPDATE cigar_flavor_scoring AS cfs

INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS wpm ON (wpm.post_id = cfs.post_id)
SET cfs.woody = wpm.meta_value
WHERE meta_key = "woody"`

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are looking to update a table using INNER JOIN.

Please check this thread - [SQL Server - inner join when updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588423/sql-server-inner-join-when-updating)

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? The person who asked the question did comment that he/she finally ended up using UPDATE with INNER JOIN.  Did not this answer provide the direction?