# Swap value of two columns in a table without using third variable or a table

Tags: sql

Swap value of two columns in a table without using third variable or a table

```
id name lastname
1  ab    cd
2  df    cx
3  sd    gh
```

I want to swap the two column

```
id name lastname
1  cd    ab
2  cx    df
3  gh    sd
```

Answer (score 1):

In almost any database, you can do:

```
update t
    set name = lastname,
        lastname = name;
```

It is standard behavior that the first assignment does not affect the second one.  The only database where this does not work -- to the best of my knowledge -- is MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to move a lot of data around, it may be easier to create a view with the names you want:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT lastname AS name, name AS lastname
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using [inner join update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588423/sql-server-inner-join-when-updating).

```
Update t1
set t1.name = t2.lastname, t1.lastname = t1.name
from <YourTableName> t1
inner join <YourTableName> t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Here is the implementation.

```
create table #temp (Id int, name varchar(20), lastname varchar(20))
insert into #temp values
('1', 'ab', 'cd'), (2, 'df', 'cx'), (3, 'sd', 'gh')

Update t1
set t1.name = t2.lastname, t1.lastname = t1.name
from #temp t1
inner join #temp t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

The output after update is as below.

```
Id  name    lastname
--------------------
1   cd     ab
2   cx     df
3   gh     sd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change column names as per you requirement. To do that perform these following steps-

1. Rename the column 'Name' to a Temporary column name 'Temp'
2. Rename the column name 'LastName' to 'Name'
3. Now rename the column 'Temp' to 'LastName'